# PriorityBlockingQueue hangs during take(): Java

Tags: java, priority-queue, freeze

The aim was to create a priority queue along with a consumer and a producer.

Now i do not wish to stop the running of the consumer when there is no data in the queue and just want that it waits till there is some data and then goes ahead and executes it. And So i want the consumer to run for the full duration of my application as there could at any time be a request in the queue.

There is only one way to add to the queue and that is thru a specific function of the Producer class. So to make sure that when the queue has some data, the Consumer spins automatically into action, I created the consumer class object inside the consructor of the producer and passed it the empty queue, with the aim that it would wait till some data is put into the queue and then pulls it out and does its job on it.

Inside the consumer there is a while loop;

```
while(true){
             {
                if (commandsQueue != null){

                    doWorkOnCommand(commandsQueue.take());

                }
                break;
        }
```

But the moment it reaches `doWorkOnCommand(commandsQueue.take());` it hangs as it does not find any data in the queue. 
But it still remains hung even when something is put into this queue at a later stage.

I was under the impression that in a priorityBlockingQueue, it waits till there is some data and then proceeds. So why is it not proceeding?

Could someone please help?

Thanks and regards,
Sunny

Edit:
Section of producer:

public class ClientImpl implements IClient{

```
private PriorityBlockingQueue<SocketCommandParams> gatewayCommandsQueue;

public ClientImpl() {
    this.gatewayCommandsQueue = new PriorityBlockingQueue<SocketCommandParams>();

    Thread socketCmdThread = new SocketThread(gatewayCommandsQueue);
    socketCmdThread.start();
}

@Override
public void sendCommandToGateway(String ipAddress, int port, ICommand command) {
    SocketCommandParams cmdParams = new SocketCommandParams(ipAddress, port, command, callback);

    gatewayCommandsQueue.put(cmdParams);

}
```

}

Consumer

```
public class SocketThread extends Thread{

    private PriorityBlockingQueue<SocketCommandParams> gatewayCommandsQueue;

public SocketThread(PriorityBlockingQueue<SocketCommandParams> gatewayCommandsQueue) {
    setGatewayCommandsQueue(gatewayCommandsQueue);
}


public void setGatewayCommandsQueue(
        PriorityBlockingQueue<SocketCommandParams> gatewayCommandsQueue) {
    this.gatewayCommandsQueue = gatewayCommandsQueue;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while(true){
        try {
            if (gatewayCommandsQueue != null){

                executeSocketCommand(gatewayCommandsQueue.take());

            }
            break;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // do something
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `But it still remains hung even when something is put into this queue at a later stage?` Are you asking us, or is that what's happening? That's the expected behaviour looking at the docs, yeah.

Comment: my bad... i am asking that why it remains hung even when at a later stage the queue is filled. shouldn't it move ahead at the point?

Comment: i have added the relative code snippets. coudl someone please help

Comment: You have 2 different queues, 1 in each class. That's why when you add in one, there's still nothing on the other queue. You should be using the same queue in both places.

Comment: no its the same queue which i am passing to the consumer. pardon my asking but where do u see the second queue?

Comment: You're right, my bad.

Comment: Why the break? at the first command it will close the while and kill the thread.

Comment: no i want to keep it running till the application is running. Only when the application is bout to close the queue is set to null and hence the thread closes

Comment: yes u r right the break should be in a else statement. but that doesn;t solve the main issue of the hang

Comment: It's not 'hanging'. It's *blocking* That's what it's supposed to do. That's why it's called a BlockingQueue.

Comment: @EJP But it was supposed to unblock when the an something is added to the queue...right? That's the OP's problem.

Comment: Had this same effect. Came from multiple surrounding instances: One queue was pushed, the other one consumed.

Answer (score -1):

Because it's how `take()` works.

> Retrieves and removes the head of this queue, waiting if necessary until an element becomes available.

More [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html#take()).

You could use `poll()` which return null instead, but i don't think it's what you need. (Well, in this case, `take()` is what you need to use.)

What is wrong with your code is a bit hard to say without more info, you use two threads to add elements to the Queue right? Well, they use the same queue or different?

Comment: both threads use the same queue and even when the queue is filled (at a later stage), it still remains hung.

Comment: Put a breakpoint and check if there are really items inside it when he reach it. Are you sure they use the same queue? I see many beginner do this kind of error. Can you add the code which adds the item inside the queue? Maybe the declaration too and how you pass the Queue instance could help.

Comment: ok when it reaches it, there is no item, but isn't that the whole purpose. That it waits there till an item is available. So how would i check that with a break point

Comment: To see if it's go back and you don't notice it due to the fast while(true) And a breakpoint inside the code which add the item could help too.

Comment: ok let me paste the full related code for producer and consumer

Comment: Think, the original post makes clear, that the trigger "until an element becomes available" is not followed. When an element becomes available, the thread waiting in "take()" should become unblocked. Insofar "Because it's how take() works." is not an answer.